# xamarin: How to handle image click on google maps infowindow click in android

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a **CustomMapRenderer** on my Droid project to deal with the map custom rending and display of custom Pin and Info Window. This is all working fine and in my function

```
public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
```

I can show the info text using the `MapInfoWindow.axml`

However I have an issue that on the form I have a Button and I want to be able  to hook in to the on click event on that **ImageView** but I notice that click event is only available on the complete InfoWindow and there is no way to specifically track the click on the individual item on that window.

I tried to use the following code to check:

```
callImage.Click += (s, e) =>
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.PhoneDialer.Open(PinCustom.MobileNo);
};
```

the call always reaches

```
NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
```

can someone please help in hooking on to the individual item click instead of working with the complete InfoWindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems could not respond the click event of **ImageView**.

> An info window is not a live View. Instead, Android will convert the
>   View to a static bitmap and display that as an image. This means that
>   while an info window can respond to a click event, it cannot respond
>   to any touch events or gestures, and the individual controls in the
>   info window cannot respond to their own click events.

you could refer to [Custom the Info Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin#customizing-the-info-window)